# Encode/Decode msbin1 on JAX-WS client

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm working with a web service that recibes Content-Type:"application/soap+msbin1" but it seems that it needs a special encode to request because i recived "Bad Request" on the response of the ws

```
public class pruebaWS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactory.setServiceClass(service.class);
    proxyFactory.setAddress("http://fakepath/service.svc");
    service port = (service) proxyFactory.create();
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port); 
   
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setContentType("application/soap+msbin1");
    httpConduit.setClient(policy);
    try {
        port.consultaDeOrdenes(new ConsultaOrdenCanalRequest());
    } catch (serviceFaultMessage e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

any ideas to how to encode the request before i send it  ?

```
Throwable occurred: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: Bad Request
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:664)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2040)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1965)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:478)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:260)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
at $Proxy60.consultaDeOrdenes(Unknown Source)
at com.rio.common.wsERI.pruebaWS.main(pruebaWS.java:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of this content type is a mandatory requirement? Could it be switched to soap+xml? It would be simpler to use a more documented standard.

Anyway, I've found this plug-in you could try to use for encode your request: https://github.com/GDSSecurity/WCF-Binary-SOAP-Plug-In

Comment: No i can't have access to the server part . Yes i saw that plug-in but i cannot find any examples .. i don't know how to use it , any idea ?